# Failed running "npm run prepare"

Tags: npm, browser, electron, yarnpkg, theia

Trying to generate a theia-extension using "yo generate-extension" but am facing an error when arriving to this instruction which is among the script

```
npm run prepare
```

where it will launch the electron-app and the browser-app. here's the error

```
$ lerna run prepare
lerna info version 2.4.0
hello-world-extension: > hello-world-extension@0.0.0 prepare
hello-world-extension: > yarn run clean && yarn run build
hello-world-extension: yarn run v1.22.19
hello-world-extension: warning package.json: No license field
hello-world-extension: $ rimraf lib
hello-world-extension: Done in 0.27s.
hello-world-extension: yarn run v1.22.19
hello-world-extension: warning package.json: No license field
hello-world-extension: $ tsc
hello-world-extension: Done in 4.82s.
browser-app: > browser-app@0.0.0 prepare
browser-app: > theia build --mode development
electron-app: > electron-app@0.0.0 prepare
electron-app: > theia build --mode development
browser-app: Failed to resolve module: msgpackr
browser-app: Failed to resolve module: socket.io
electron-app: RequestError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com\n
```

Comment: hmmm not sure but ... could it be that you're working from behind a proxy? In that case you may need to configure yarn